# Magento shopping cart rule, apply only to matching products not working

Tags: magento

I am working with Magento 1.8.1. I set up a promotion which applies when the basket contains a product in a list of categories. This promotion works OK.

Then I add the requirement to apply the discount only to items in that list of categories. The rule stops working.

If I remove this requirement, then the rule works again.

The list of categories is exactly the same. The difference is that, in the first case, the rule is applied if there is at least one product from that list of categories, but the discount is applied to all products. In the second, the discount is applied only to products in that categories.

The rule I am setting in the "apply only to matching items" is the following:

if ANY|ALL of these conditions are TRUE (tried with both):
category IS|IS ONE OF (tried both) list of category IDs

The same condition in the "conditions" section works fine.

What am I doing wrong?